# Swift fatal error

Tags: ios, swift

I want to go back to mainviewcontroller when I hit logout button, but it gives me:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(logOut))


 func logOut(){

    let mainViewController = MainViewController()
    present(mainViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: is this controller embed in navigation controller?

Comment: if not, have you tried just dismiss current controller (it seems that you don't want to create new instance of mainViewController, you want to go back to this controller).

Comment: Yes.  MainViewController is first after navigationController

Comment: Already tried to dismiss, didn't work

Comment: if you have it embed in navigation controller (both of them: main and current one), you have to use self.navigationController.popViewController or popToRootViewController.

popViewController will bring you back to the previous controller, and popToRoot — to the first (root) controller in navigation.

Comment: It works, but it writes that "expression of type UIViewController is unused"

Comment: oh, yeah. in swift 3 it is advised to use "_ = self.navigationController.popViewController" instead of "self.navigationController.popViewController". (or, maybe, "let _ = ...", try this if the first option won't work)

Comment: First one worked, thank you!